# Setting JAVA_HOME for JDK 11 in Ubuntu for VSCODE

Tags: java, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, java-home

How do I set JAVA_HOME for JDK 11 in Ubuntu for Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 13):

### 1 - Install jdk-11 or higher lts version via bash terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

### 2- Find java path via bash terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Obs.: It will returns you a path like this:

**/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java** (copy this path)

### 3- Edit /.bashrc adding **JAVA_HOME** to it via bash terminal:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

The code above will open the file, insert **JAVA_HOME** in the end of this, be careful, do not change anything here, just adding this code and SAVE:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

Obs.: JAVA_HOME= **put your java path without "/bin/java" here **

### 4- Set Vscode jdk path variable:

-press **F1** and type **Sttings Sync: Show Settings**

-inside serarch settings put **@tag:sync**

-find and open **settings.json** like this:

[image]

-now you just need to put your **JAVA_HOME** like this:

```
    "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64",
    
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name":"JavaSE-11",
            "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
        }
    ],
```

[image]

**reload vscode window, or just close it and open agin**

...and **VOALA**!
now the JDK is visible * -- *

[image]

Comment: You may mark your answer for others to know directly that it's a solution.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still saying "The java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings does not point to a JDK."

Comment: very nice. works well for me

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks

Comment: please fix the typos. Thanks.

Comment: For me I am having `The java.jdt.ls.java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java) does not point to a JDK.` output of  `readlink -f $(which java)` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` and I do not have other jdk. What might be the problem?